# Can React Native's PlatformColor get colors for dark mode when the system is in light mode?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I can't find any details on whether or not [`PlatformColor`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platformcolor) can access colors that aren't part of the currently selected system theme.

For example, if the system theme is set to "light," can we get the colors for dark mode?

Comment: yes, you can. You just change condition of theme

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? I've read over the docs and played with it but I don't understand still.

Comment: `<View style={[styles.container, {...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        color: PlatformColor('label'),
        backgroundColor:
          PlatformColor(colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'systemBrown' : 'systemPink'),
      },
      android: {
        color: PlatformColor('?android:attr/textColor'),
        backgroundColor:
          PlatformColor('@android:color/holo_blue_bright'),
      },
      default: { color: 'black' }
    })}]}>
    <Text style={styles.label}>
      I am a special label color!
    </Text>
  </View>`

Comment: all the docs have small example but it change color of text, if you want to change color when your phone in dark mode or light mode u need combine with `useColorScheme`, About the color in platform, you follow this link to understand [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/rn-tester/js/examples/PlatformColor/PlatformColorExample.js)

Comment: Unfortunately the code in that link just produces a list of black text on a white background on my Android 12 device. I don't know what to make of that.